# My system setting gear disappeared from the dock, how do I get it back?

Tags: system-settings

All I did was install some applications and they filled up the dock, but now the system setting gear is missing and when I try to open it from the " about this computer " pull down window it doesn't work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press the Super (or Windows) key to invoke the dash.
2. type "system" in the search field.
3. The "system settings" icon will appear among the search results. Click it to open System Settings.
4. It will appear in the dock again. Right-click it and select "lock to launcher" to pin it there even if it's closed.